# Per-project indent space in PyDev

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

For some projects we use 2-spaces indentation and for others 4-spaces. I know how to change the indentation size in PyDev settings, but I don't know how to set it on a per-project basis.

So my questions are:

- Is it possible to set a per-project indent size in PyDev?
- If it is, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go to the preferences (`PyDev > Editor > Tabs), configure the tab-length to the value you want and use the`Save to ...`>`Project settings ...` button to save that configuration to a project (see screenshot below).

It should create a file under `project/.settings/org.python.pydev.yaml` with the proper contents (which you should commit to your vcs so that other users will have the setting correct too).

[image: Tab preferences for PyDev]